# MySQL querying id from first name and last name

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a messaging system for my website and stumbled across a problem.

In my users table, all users have a column of `fname` and `lname` (first name and last name).

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
   <input type='text' name='recipient' />
   <input type='text' name='message' />
   <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

How can I query a user's id by first name and last name if the first name and last name is stored in separate columns in the database?

My code that is incorrect:

`mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE fname AND lname = '$_POST['recipient']'");`

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to split `$_POST['recipient']` into first name and last name lets call them `$fname` and `$lname`.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE fname = '$fname' AND lname = '$lname'");
```

Also, you should call mysql_real_escape string or some other function that safely escapes user input to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: And you have case to worry about too  :-)